# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.proxy.EntityNotFoundDelegate

Tags: hibernate, maven, tomcat, jpa

I deploys a web application with JSF, hibernate, tomcat7, JAVA EE 5 and maven.
I get an error that I can not solve:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/hibernate/proxy/EntityNotFoundDelegate    at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:55)
>     at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
>     at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
>     at
>   entity.ActeurexterneController.getJpaController(ActeurexterneController.java:44)
>     at
>   entity.ActeurexterneController.access$000(ActeurexterneController.java:23)
>     at
>   entity.ActeurexterneController$1.createPageDataModel(ActeurexterneController.java:59)
>     at
>   entity.ActeurexterneController.getItems(ActeurexterneController.java:159)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)  at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)    at
>   org.apache.el.parser.AstEqual.getValue(AstEqual.java:38)  at
>   org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:413)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1750)
>     at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1756)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:401)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:410)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.hibernate.proxy.EntityNotFoundDelegate    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)

my persitane.xml :

> ```
>   <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"/>
>   <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
>   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
>   <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
>   <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
>   <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prosper"/>
>   <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</property>
> ```

and in my pom.xml :

> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>         <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
>         <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
>         <scope>provided</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
>         <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>         <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
>         <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

Thx :)

Answer (score 1):

In given pom.xml scope *provided* is used for hibernate-core dependency. It means that dependency should be provided by runtime environment. Tomcat 7 is not shipped with Hibernate, that's why it does make sense to use scope *provided* in this context.

Problem is fixed by removing scope. Then we will fall back to default scope, which is *compile*. It means that dependency is available also in runtime (packed with application as well).